# Map Display in French

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-groups

I am attempting to get a map I am working on to display in french, so I added "language=fr" at the end of the address under src in my script tag. After I did this, the copyright notice at the bottom was in french but none of the cities or map names were changed to french. For example 'Nova Scotia' should say 'Nouvelle Ecosse' but doesn't. Does google maps api v3 provide this functionality?

thanks,

g

Answer (score 0):

No, the localization only supports *"displaying textual information such as the names for controls, copyright notices, driving directions and labels on maps"*.  You could try adding region=FR to the URL, but I think that will only help with *"biasing geocoding results towards the region"*, i.e. if searching on place names it'll be more likely to find a place in France than in the user's actual location.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html#Localization

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you know if there is a way I can manually change names on the map to their french equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, using that language parameter should work, but doesn't. Try changing it to ja and you'll see the results in Japanese. This could mean either there's a bug, or Google doesn't have French names for places in Canada. You can edit the names in [Google Map Maker](http://www.google.com/mapmaker)

Comment: I'm not sure Google Map Maker will allow you to rename destinations like Novia Scotia!  In fact when I try to edit Novia Scotia, it says "This feature has been locked. It cannot be edited"

Comment: Ah, in which case you can report a problem on maps.google.com. I'll file a bug internally.

Comment: Hi, I tried it in japanese and it worked. It still won't work in french. Where on maps.google.com can I report a problem? I didn't notice any contact information on that page.

Comment: I went back to the team, we don't currently have French labels for everything. I filed a bug, but there's currently no workaround.

Comment: It's not a bug. Google team hasn't implemented it yet for French. They're slowly adding localized place names for various languages. Obviously they've done it for English. Japanese is another one, as mentioned by Mano Marks. I think Russian works too. French is in the pipe, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do this for Canadian place names by grabbing a list from the geonames site, using a map style to hide place names, and writing the place names on an overlay as if they were markers. It works really well, considering how much data is involved. You mentioned Nova Scotia...are you just interested in French-Canadian place names?

Update: I've extracted the relevant code from the rest of my app, and shared it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DaveSchindler/HkuYx/5/). It uses a modified version of [this MapLabel library](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/maplabel/docs/reference.html) to add the labels to the map. The modified version replaces the canvas-only code with SVG/VML code with help from the wonderful [Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/) library. The code I'm sharing is only the French side of the code. The if/else code for the French/English in my app is done server-side, so I left it out.

My client for this code only cared about bilingual place names that are different in French/English (ie pan-Canadian geonames), so the labels you'll see in the code, are the ones from categories where there are both a French and an English name for at least one of the places in that category.

Comment: Although I would prefer it if I could get the labels on the entire map to display in french, I would be content if I could get it working solely for Canada, more specifically atlantic canada. What is involved in the process you described? How do you create an overlay as if using markers?

Comment: Did you use the geonames web service to get the place names?

Comment: I think it was the service from this site: http://www.nrcan.gc.ca/earth-sciences/search/index_e.php